# how to delete the word for all elements in the list in python?

Tags: python

I have a list like the below:

```
wheelbase = 
[<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>,<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>, <td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>,<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>,<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>,<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>,<td>-</td>,<td>48.8 inches [123 cm]</td>,<td>48.8 inches [123 cm]</td>]
```

I want to delete the `<td>` and `</td>` from the all elements in the list.

I tried the below but non-type error occurred.

```
wheelbase[:] = [s.replace('<td>', '') for s in wheelbase]
```

I want the list like below:

```
[53.2 inches [135 cm],53.2 inches [135 cm]53.2 inches [135 cm],53.2 inches [135 cm],53.2 inches [135 cm],53.2 inches [135 cm], -, 48.8 inches [123 cm], 48.8 inches [123 cm]]
```

Comment: res = [i.replace('<td>','').replace('</td>','') for i in wheelbase]

Comment: @N. Arunoprayoch ," 'NoneType' object is not callable" comes out  from the replace function

Comment: your list isnt even strings that's why, we can't even copy and paste your list into python to try anything

Comment: @YangJongHyun Please change your elements to strings.

Comment: @YangJongHyun Are you using `beautifulsoup`? The elements in list are tags extracted from `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: @ Andrej Kesely yes those are extracted by beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem your list elements aren't `string` type. That is the reason why you got the `NoneType` issue.

```py
>>>str(wheelbase)[1:-1].replace("</td>","").replace("<td>","").split(",")
['53.2 inches [135 cm]', '53.2 inches [135 cm]', ' 53.2 inches [135 cm]', '53.2 inches [135 cm]', '53.2 inches [135 cm]', '53.2 inches [135 cm]', '-', '48.8 inches [123 cm]', '48.8 inches [123 cm]']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wheelbase = ['<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>','<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>', '<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>','<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>',
 '<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>','<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>','<td>-</td>','<td>48.8 inches [123 cm]</td>','<td>48.8 inches [123 cm]</td>']
print([a.replace("</td>","").replace("<td>","") for a in wheelbase])
```

Comment: I tired your code, but still 'NoneType' error comes out...

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-6f61c0044cd4> in <module>
     82 
     83 
---> 84 print([a.replace("</td>","").replace("<td>","") for a in wheelbase])
     85 

<ipython-input-64-6f61c0044cd4> in <listcomp>(.0)
     82 
     83 
---> 84 print([a.replace("</td>","").replace("<td>","") for a in wheelbase])
     85 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Your list looks like: `[<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>,<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>,...]`
My list looks like: `['<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>','<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>',...]`.
It's should be strings, not "NoneType".

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure element start with `<td>` end with `</td>`, I think you can use slice:

`wheelbase = [i[4:-5] for i in wheelbase]`

Answer (score 0):

```
wheelbase = ['<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>','<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>', '<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>','<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>',
 '<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>','<td>53.2 inches [135 cm]</td>','<td>-</td>','<td>48.8 inches [123 cm]</td>','<td>48.8 inches [123 cm]</td>']

wheelbase = [i.split('<td>')[1].split('</td>')[0] for i in wheelbase]
```